# Proper loadbalancing EC2 instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am pretty new to AWS and want to build a simple example auto scaling wordpress application with EC2 instances.
I understand how to create a loadbalancer, how to create bitnami wordpress ec2 instances and a autoscaling group and get all running but here is what i dont get and cannot find in any documentation:

Every EC2 Wordpress instance that i create has obviously its own wordpress data and database. They are not synchronized. So if the Load Balancer sends the Traffic to EC2 A the user will see an other Appplication set then EC2 B.

How do people set this up / solve this to be able to add unlimited ressources which hold the same application / work for the same Application.

Comment: Not sure this is worthy of an answer, but there's a CloudFormation template doing this here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-applications-eu-west-1.html (the WordPress scalable and durable template)

Answer (score 1):

Running Wordpress behind a Load Balancer (ELB) is a little bit tricky as by default Wordpress is storing data on volumes of the EC2 instances.

A possible solution:

- Use RDS to launch a managed MySQL database and connect Wordpress to it.
- Outsource the user uploads to S3 with Wordpress plugins amazon-web-services and amazon-s3-and-cloudfront.

But beware: you need to disable auto-update, the Wordpress theme gallery, ... and everything else that is changing files on a single EC2 instance.

I've written a blog post covering that topic: https://cloudonaut.io/wordpress-on-aws-you-are-holding-it-wrong/ some time ago.

Alternatives:

- Use a distributed file system (e.g. GlusterFS) to store all Wordpress files.
- Use CloudFront (CDN) to cache incoming requests and run everything on a single EC2 instance.

Comment: How about handling theme changes, plugin updates / installations and so on. If i understand it right what you say all of this cant be done live but has to be done in an local enviroment and uploaded as a new version or something?

Comment: And will the plugin you mentioned be able to also cover pictures in posts / Pages and so on (basicly the whole mediathek?)

Comment: As i may forgot to mention is that one more problem i had is, that if i deploy the application and do specific enviroment changes like an ec2 upgrade the application gets resettet to the uploading status, which kills all filesystem changes wordpress did like installing a theme. Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: You have to handle updates, themes, plugings as part of your deployment process/pipeline.

Comment: meinst du wir können mal eine Skype Session machen? Ich bezahle dir gerne ein paar Beratungsstunden

Comment: Please have a look at my profile to find contact details.

Answer (score 0):

There is official best practices and blog post. Check here
https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx1TRYG42UP11ET/WordPress-on-AWS-Whitepapers